# MSI Install over network with Admin Rights

Tags: msi

I have been asked to install software.msi over a network to a group of users as they logon. My issue is that they also need admin rights to install this software. I have tried using runas command but it askes the user to input a password. I have also tried using MSIEXEC but still stating user has not enough privalages. Giving users admin rights accross the network or locally is also no an option. Help please!

Andy.

Comment: Are these systems in a domain?  Can't you just use a group policy?

Comment: You are using a group policy for the user's Organizational Unit to deploy the msi? What is your server OS? What are the OSs of the clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Group Policy available, use the "Always install with elevated privileges" option: User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Installer.

Comment: Thanks mate you pushed me in the right direction and i think i have this sorted now, Cheers